# Cannot select the scala sdk when using Intellij after installed the scala plugin

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Everyone, thanks for your attention.

I'm using Intellij IDEA 2017.2 in windows 7, with Scala plugin installed.(I downloaded directly from the [web](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1347-scala) and installed it from local disk.)

But when I wanna to add Scala sdk through "Project Structure-Global Libraries" , I clicked the menu "Scala sdk" which is shown in the picture below, it didn't appear by the popup window as expected, i.e, it didn't present anything.
So I cannot select the Scala sdk.

[the picture describes the scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Znp2Y.png)

What should I do to make it work in Intellij? My scala version is 2.12.2.
Any advices will be appreciated.

Comment: You've probably installed some incompatible Scala plug-in. Try installing from the IDE instead, check [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) for errors.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for viewed and replied.I have found the problem.

It's wired. After I created a new project, I added scala sdk successfully within this project's structure.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the Scala SDK selection doing nothing. (IntelliJ CE 2018.1 on macOS 10.13.2). To change my version of Scala (in this case going from 2.12 to 2.11 for Spark support), I deleted the 2.12 SDK from Global Libraries and noticed that IntelliJ could still build/run the project. So I changed the symlink it was reading the Scala library from to point to a 2.11 install. After restart IntelliJ still has no Scala SDK under Global Libraries and the button to add it still doesn't work, but it is using 2.11 which is all I needed.

I also tried Jimmy Liu's fix of creating a new Scala project but it didn't seem to have an effect.